# Python Celery could start with a threading inprocess ?

Tags: python, celery

I want make a testcase with my celery codes.
But usually celery need start with a new process like `$ celery -A CELERY_MODULE worker`, It's means I can't run my testcase code directly ?

I'm configurate the Celery with memory store to void the extra I/O in the testcase. That's config can't sample share the task queue in different process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my naive implements.
The celery entry from `celery.bin.celeryd.WorkCommand`, it's parse the args and execute works.
Use the `solo` to void the MultiProcess use in the case. Of course you need install that's lib first.

You could use this before your celery testcase start.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#vim: encoding=utf-8

import time
import unittest
from threading import Thread

from celery import Celery, states
from celery.bin.celeryd import WorkerCommand

class CELERY_CONFIG(object):
    BROKER_URL = "memory://"
    CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = "memory"
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "cache"
    CELERYD_POOL = "solo"

class CeleryTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_inprocess(self):
        app = Celery(__name__)
        app.config_from_object(CELERY_CONFIG)

        @app.task
        def dumpy_task(dct):
            return 321

        worker = WorkerCommand(app)
        #worker.execute_from_commandline(["-P solo"])
        t = Thread(target=worker.execute_from_commandline, args=(["-c 1"],))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        ar = dumpy_task.apply_async(({"a": 123},))
        while ar.status != states.SUCCESS:
            time.sleep(.01)
        self.assertEqual(states.SUCCESS, ar.status)
        self.assertEqual(ar.result, 321)
        t.join(0)
```